# How to config EOL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse in Windows. However, other people in my group mostly write code in linux.
This cause a conflict of EOL. How can I change the EOL from \r\n to \n?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. To do this for all projects in your workspace, from the menu bar

   ```
   Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > New text file line delimiter
   ```

   [image: Setting the EOL explicitly for the complete workspace]
2. To do it on a per-project basis, go to your project's `Properties` and select `Resource` from the sidebar to get the same option of `New text file line delimiter`

Answer (score 5):

You have to select your project (click on it) then go to "File > Convert Line Delimiter To" and choose Windows / Unix / MacOS 9.

This works with Eclipse 3.6.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

right click on your project folder, choose **"Properties"**, in the popup dialog, click on **"Resource"**, you will see the section: **"New text file line delimiter"**, tick **"Other"**, then you can choose: **Windows, Linux, Mac OS**