# A bug in SVN commit using tortoisesvn app?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn

My colleague is using Eclipse as the main IDE and he issues SVN commits using the 3rd party app TortoiseSVN (Windows). I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 on Ubuntu.

When I update changes from SVN using IDEA's SVN Update feature, I often see that **not all files have been properly updated**. Force update does not help as well. The only thing that helps in such cases is to create a new folder and to checkout to that folder. He, on the other hand, gets no errors during committing to SVN.

I was unable to find the concrete use-case scenario when and how this happens, as at this moment this is happening randomly.

Are there any know bugs when Eclipse user does commit via TortoiseSVN and IDEA user is updating from that repository? Any ideas why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Tala is correct technically, ideologically using external program is wrong choice.

If problem is really EOL-style (I'm sure it's true, but it have to be re-checked with diff), Subversion has own tool for resolving such type of issues: `svn:eol-style` property, which, properly defined for text-files **on both sides**, give the ability to auto-convert EOL to OS-specific type.

You (and colleague )can define svn:eol-style globally (per host) in config-file, or in shared project root only for all affected by problem files and find best-suited combination of `eol-style` values on both sides.

I *suppose* (**not tested!!!**) `svn:eol-style=native` will be OK (EOL *in Working Copies* will be transformed automatically to OS-dictated type, AFAICR)

Comment: hm this is definitely worth trying. it's better that this is causing problems than the bug...

Comment: For those who don't know how to set EOL in Eclipse -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501521/how-to-config-eol-in-eclipse

Comment: We set Eclipse EOL to Unix and now we will be testing this for a couple of days to see if the same scenario will reappear or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. In our case `dos2unix` (DOS/Mac to Unix and vice versa text file format converter) helped to resolve the issue . Also note that there is `unix2dos` command that might also help.

Wikipedia link [unix2dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos)